# non-trivial common zero of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The following situation occurs in a proof that I would like to understand: we have polynomials $F_1,\ldots, F_N$ in $k[X_1,\ldots,X_M]$, where $k$ is of characteristic zero and algebraically closed. The polynomials $F_i$ are homogeneous of positive degree. And we have $M>N$.

Now I would like to conclude that these polynomials have a common zero $\neq (0,\ldots,0)$.

(the following seems to be wrong)
By Hilbert's Nullstellensatz it would be enough to show that the ideal $(F_1,\ldots,F_N)$ is proper. This should be easy (probably by looking at dimensions and using $M>N$?), but somehow I don't see a nice argument for that.

Comment: If it weren't proper it would contain units (constant polynomials) which are of grade zero. This is impossible here, since elements of the ideal must have degree larger than that of the generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the $F_i$ are homogeneous of positive degree $(F_1, \ldots, F_N) \subset (X_1, \ldots, X_M) \neq k[X_1,\ldots,X_M]$. So do we need $M > N$?

Comment: Ok you're right about that. It might be not enough to show that the ideal is proper, since for example $x+y$ and $x^2+y^2$ have only one common zero: $(0,0)$. So, how can I check if there are non-trivial common zeros, if not by checking properness of the ideal?

Comment: I have found a proof now, it's a proposition in Chapter 1, §6.2 in Safarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry.